# How can I turn this function into a unfunc without for loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

I am trying to plot a function I created against a range of values (y-axis vs. x-axis).

The operation I would like to compute is common in "matrix multiplication" :

```
r^T * C * r
```

where r^T should be of shape `(1,100)`, r of shape `(100,1)`, and C is a matrix of shape `(100,100)` (or an ndarray shape 100,100) . Multiplied together using `numpy.dot()`, the output should be a single value.

The function only has one input, which can be an array of data.

```
import numpy as np

# The user first sets the values used by the function
# Not "true code", because input() too complex for the question at hand

r = data                        # an numpy ndarray of 100 values, (100,)
original_matrix =  M            # set matrix, such that M.shape = (100, 100)
param = array of data           # EITHER an array of values, shape (50,), 
                                # OR one value, i.e. a 32/64-bit float
                                # e.g. parameters = np.array of 50 values

def function(param):
    # using broadcasting, "np.sum(param * original_matrix for i in r)"
    new_matrix = np.sum(param[:, None, None] * original_matrix, axis=0)
    # now perform r^T * C * r
    return np.dot( r.transpose(), np.dot( new_matrix,  r) )
```

Calling the function

```
function(param)
```

results in *one* value, in format = `numpy.float64`.

I would like to plot this function against a series of values, i.e. I need this function to input a np.array and output a np.cdarray, must like other `ufuncs` in `NumPy`. The function will evaluate each element in the ndarray, and plot this as a function.

For example,

```
import pylab

X = np.arange(100)
Y = sin(X)
pylab.plot(X, Y)
```

outputs

[image]

Given that my original function (which is solely a function of the array "parameters") results in `np.float64` format, how can I turn this function into a `ufunc`? I would like to plot my function on the y-axis against parameters on the x-axis.

Comment: What do you mean paramaters on the x-axis? Do you have a list of paramater-arrays that you want to iterate over and find y-values for?

Comment: Hopefully the post is more clear now. 
The function is dependent solely on the array of parameters, `param`. The y-axis is this function, `function(param)`, plotted against the array of values 'param'. 
For the sake of discussion, take `param = np.arange(50)`

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your function to take a single paramater rather than an array?

Then you could just do

```
X = range(50)
Y = [function(x) for x in X]
pylab.plot(X, Y)
```

Comment: For loops tend to slow down Python so as to be unmanageable for large data sets, even if one is using NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer two solutions

- You can make (almost) any function a `ufunc` using `np.vectorize` which handles numbers as well as np.arrays like the `np.sin` function

  ```
  def my_func_1(param):
      # using broadcasting, "np.sum(param * original_matrix for i in r)"
      new_matrix = np.sum(param * original_matrix[None,:,:], axis=0)
      # now perform r^T * C * r
      return np.dot( r.transpose(), np.dot( new_matrix,  r) )

  my_vec_func_1 = np.vectorize(my_func_1)
  ```

  Note that `np.vectorize` does not really vectorize your code ... I just makes automatically a `for`loop if an array is passed as an argument. There is not gain in runtime by using it ... see the timings below.
- You can define a truly vectorized function which takes (for the following code) *only* one-dimensional lists or `np.arrays` as an argument:

  ```
  def my_vec_func_2(param):
      param = np.asarray(param)
      new_matrix = np.sum(param[:,None,None,None] * original_matrix[None,None,:,:],axis=1)
      return np.dot(r, np.dot(new_matrix,r).transpose())
  ```

  Truly vectorized codes are usually considerably faster than `for`loops. Why the gain is so small in this case I can not explain for this case ...

**Timings**

I used the following code to test the runtime

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

r = randint(10,size=(100))                       # an numpy ndarray of 100 values, (100,)
original_matrix =  randint(30,size=(100,100)) 

timeit my_vec_func_1(np.arange(10000))
1 loops, best of 3: 508 ms per loop

timeit my_vec_func_2(np.arange(10000))
1 loops, best of 3: 488 ms per loop

timeit [my_func_1(x) for x in np.arange(10000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 505 ms per loop
```